# How to convert Class to Function in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is my Component screen. Here is Class but I want to convert that to Function...

Here is that Class component I want to convert to function:

```
class ReadingComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

    }

    redirectTo(screenName: any) {
        useNavigation().navigate(`${screenName}`);
    }
```

Here are FlatList items:

```
    render() {
        
    let categories = [ 
        {
            name : "Category 1",
            img : require("../Assets/Slika.jpg"),
            screenName : "Player",
        },
        {
            name : "Category 2",
            img : require("../Assets/Slika.jpg"),
            screenName : "Player1",
        },
    ];
```

Here is return and flatlist details:

```
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={categories}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    numColumns={categories.length / 5}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    renderItem = {({item, index}) => {
                        return (
                        <TouchableOpacity 
                            onPress={() => this.redirectTo(item.screenName)}>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        );
                    }}
                />
            </View>
            
        );    
    }
}
```

Comment: check React docs, it's simple: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 1):

```
export default (props) => {
    
    const redirectTo = (screenName: any) => {
        useNavigation().navigate(`${screenName}`);
    }
        
    const categories = [ 
        {
            name : "Category 1",
            img : require("../Assets/Slika.jpg"),
            screenName : "Player",
        },
        {
            name : "Category 2",
            img : require("../Assets/Slika.jpg"),
            screenName : "Player1",
        },
    ];

    return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={categories}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    numColumns={categories.length / 5}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    renderItem = {({item, index}) => {
                        return (
                        <TouchableOpacity 
                            onPress={() => redirectTo(item.screenName)}>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        );
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        );    
}
```

Comment: I think this one is the answer, probably would be better to add some explanation on the answer rather than giving a straight answer in code.

Comment: You are right. I also don't like when no explanation is given but in this case I searched what can I add and didn't find.